# Combine elements of one foreach into another

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, simple-html-dom

I have two foreach loops where I would like to match the output from the first with the second.  The first grabs a title from a starting page while the second foreach navigates to a sub-page for a description.  I cant seem to output the two inline with each other such that the title is displayed with the associated description.

```
//1st foreach:

$title = array();
foreach ($html->find('.event-box .event-details h1') as $t){
        $title[] = $t->plaintext;
    }
    echo implode('<br>',$title);'<br>';
 //this lists all $title found on page ahead of the below foreach (obvisouly)

//2nd foreach:

    // loop through each link
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    // Create the new link to follow and parse
    $urlTemp = $baseUrl . $anchor->href;
    $html2 = new simple_html_dom();
    $html2->load_file($urlTemp);

    //Descriptions
    foreach($html2->find('div[id=content-area]') as $article) {
    }   $para = array();
        foreach($article->find('p') as $p) {
                $para[] = $p->innertext;    }


    echo 'DESC: '.implode('<br>',$para);'<br>';
    echo "<hr/>";

    $html2->clear(); 
    unset($htm2);
}
```

I would like to get the output in this order so the `$title` follows in line with `$para` for each iteration.  `$title` needs to match up with `$para`

```
$title //From first foreach - 1st in $title[]
$para //From second foreach - 1st in $para[]
</hr>
$title //From first foreach - 2nd in $title[]
$para //From second foreach - 2nd in $para[]
</hr>
$title
$para
```

.... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an index key to the foreach.  Like:

```
    $i=0;

    foreach ($anchors as $key=>$anchor) { 
    //...........
    echo 'TITLE: '.$title[$i].'<br>';
    //...........
    $i++;
```

That what the array element from the first foreach matches the index key of the second `$title[1], $title[2]` etc can be acheived with `$title[$i]`